# Get generated tablename for an entity?

Tags: linq-to-sql

If I have the type of my entity generated by linq2sql, how can I get the name of the table the entity belongs to? I want the tablename generated by linq2sql not the database table name.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that last sentence? ("I want the tablename generated by linq2sql not the database table name.").

Comment: Linq2Sql generates classes with the name of the table but in plural, I have a database in which the table names are in singular, so it makes the name plural.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that would get all table names from a database. You could easily modify this to get the name of a single table.

```
var model = yourDBContext.Mapping;
foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
    Console.WriteLine(mt.TableName);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. Anyway, you cannot get the name of a single table out of that list without knowing the table name in advance or at least knowing it's index in the list you are getting back, so it's useless if you want a specific name programmatically.